# Duplicate inserts with scheduled job through sql server Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a job that is scheduled through SQL Agent. It is scheduled to run every 2 minutes. When I am looking at the job history log I see it has ran once. But when I am looking at the table it has inserted two records and time difference between 2 records is just few milliseconds.

I am trying to find out why it is happening and to looking to prevent this from happening.
Sql server version i'm using is 2008 on Windows server 2008.

The stored procedure is doest not any prolem and before inserting i have a check IF NOT EXISTS (in the table)then insert. And also there is no trigger on that table.

Thank you

Comment: remove any nolock hints in your query , and check your proc has any 2 inserts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no 'nolock hint', also no two insert statement.There are few select statement with that table and finally insert. Since the difference is of few milliseconds beween two records the possiblity of job re-run in case of failure is also not der.